# Python pandas .loc multiple conditions and modify part of date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, multiple-conditions

I have a DataFrame with (among others) two date columns formatted like this:

```
cap['DateCollecte'] = pd.to_datetime(cap['Date de collecte']+' '+cap['Heure de collecte'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')
cap['DatePose'] = pd.to_datetime(cap['Date de pose']+' '+cap['Heure de pose'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')
```

I know that some of them have an error: the year of DatePose is 2010 and the year of DateCollecte is 2011. The year of DatePose should be 2011 too.
The idea of what I'd like to do is more or less :

```
cap.loc[(cap.DateCollecte.dt.year == 2011) & (cap.DatePose.dt.year == 2010), cap.DatePose.dt.year] = 2011
```

I think the tricky part is that I just want to change the year part of the date. Is there a way to do this?

In the worst case, since it only concerns 3 rows with different dates (but same year problem) I could do it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your mask and add a `DateOffset`, example:

```
In [43]:
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2011,1,1), dt.datetime(2012,1,1), freq='M'), 'b':pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2010,6,1), dt.datetime(2011,6,1), freq='M')})
df

Out[43]:
            a          b
0  2011-01-31 2010-06-30
1  2011-02-28 2010-07-31
2  2011-03-31 2010-08-31
3  2011-04-30 2010-09-30
4  2011-05-31 2010-10-31
5  2011-06-30 2010-11-30
6  2011-07-31 2010-12-31
7  2011-08-31 2011-01-31
8  2011-09-30 2011-02-28
9  2011-10-31 2011-03-31
10 2011-11-30 2011-04-30
11 2011-12-31 2011-05-31

In [65]:
df.loc[(df['a'].dt.year == 2011) & (df['b'].dt.year == 2010), 'b'] = df['b'] + pd.DateOffset(years=1)
df

Out[65]:
            a          b
0  2011-01-31 2011-06-30
1  2011-02-28 2011-07-31
2  2011-03-31 2011-08-31
3  2011-04-30 2011-09-30
4  2011-05-31 2011-10-31
5  2011-06-30 2011-11-30
6  2011-07-31 2011-12-31
7  2011-08-31 2011-01-31
8  2011-09-30 2011-02-28
9  2011-10-31 2011-03-31
10 2011-11-30 2011-04-30
11 2011-12-31 2011-05-31
```

In the general case you can use `apply` to dynamically apply the difference:

```
In [69]:
df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['b'] + pd.DateOffset(years=x['a'].year-x['b'].year), axis=1)
df

Out[69]:
            a          b
0  2011-01-31 2011-06-30
1  2011-02-28 2011-07-31
2  2011-03-31 2011-08-31
3  2011-04-30 2011-09-30
4  2011-05-31 2011-10-31
5  2011-06-30 2011-11-30
6  2011-07-31 2011-12-31
7  2011-08-31 2011-01-31
8  2011-09-30 2011-02-28
9  2011-10-31 2011-03-31
10 2011-11-30 2011-04-30
11 2011-12-31 2011-05-31
```